# How to scrape an object by css class with python?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the number from a website by its css class. The output of my code below returns `None`.

```
url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/" + subreddit
content = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')

active_users = soup.find("div", {"class":"_3XFx6CfPlg-4Usgxm0gK8R"})
print(active_users)
```

The class I'm trying to find is of the number of currently active users on the website.
How do I make this work?

Comment: Why not include some of the HTML you're trying to scrape?

Answer (score 1):

You can use their JSON api to get active user count, subscribers etc.

For example:

```
import json
import requests


subreddit = 'python'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}
data = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/{}/about.json'.format(subreddit), headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print('Subscribers       :', data['data']['subscribers'])
print('Active user count :', data['data']['active_user_count'])
```

Prints:

```
Subscribers       : 604566
Active user count : 2719
```

Comment: Oh, I see, I should've thought to check that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try to use `soup.select()` instead.
For example:

```
import requests, bs4, os
content = requests.get('https://getbootstrap.com/')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')

active_users = soup.select("div", {"class":"row"})

print(active_users)

for elem in active_users:
    print(elem)
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I have used 'select' instead of 'find'. Unfortunately, this still doesn't work. Now the output seems to be just the html of the site.